# How to load data from an api with React Native

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, react-native

I am loading images from an api, that I will implement into a grid. My images though are not being displayed because they are undefined. Here are some functions of my component. Images and isLoading are both defined in the constructor as an empty array and to true.

```
componentWillMount() {
api().then((res) => {
this.state.images.push(res);
}).done();

 this._load10Images();
 this.setState({isLoading:false}); // is loading is set to false 
}                                 // after images loaded.

_getImageUrls(){
 api().then((res) => {
this.state.images.push(res);
 console.log(this.state.images); //right here works array is growing
 console.log(this.state.images[0]);//with image uris
}).done();
}

_load10Images(){
 for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
this._getImageUrls(); //call _getImageUrls 10 times to fill array
 }


}

_loadImageGrid(){

  if(this.state.isLoading){
 return <Text>Loaading ...</Text>
}
else{
 console.log(this.state.images[0]); // coming back as undefined
 return <Text>not loading ...</Text>
   }
 }

render(){ return <View>
      {this._loadImageGrid()} 
       </View>
     }
```

The image array come back as undefined in the render function and the _loadImageGrid function.

Comment: Changing the state property as you do is pointless. You need to use setState to trigger a new render pass.

Comment: @flq I think I see what you are saying, can you elaborate?

Comment: haha, see answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the following functions:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        images: []
    }

}
_addImage(image) {
    let images = Object.assign([], this.state.images);
    images.push(image);
    this.setState({images});
}
```

Then you can use it like this

```js
api().then((res) => {
    this._addImage(res);
});
```

Hope it helps!